# How to return value from onResponse

Tags: java, android, retrofit, wait

How I can return value from Retrofit 2 query or do something similar?
I need to return isConnected variable.
Problem is when I call testConnection() it automatically returns false because the request sent to the server has not yet been processed.
I have to wait for the request to be processed, but how?

```
static boolean isConnected = false;

public static boolean testConnection() {
        
        apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(Api.class);
        
        Call<String> call = apiInterface.testConnection();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                
                if (response.body().equals("Connected")) {
                    isConnected = true;
                } else {
                    isConnected = false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("infomessage", t.getMessage());
                isConnected = false;
            }
        });
        return isConnected;
    }
```

Comment: might be useful to you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Answer (score 0):

the `enqueue` function runs your API call in the background, a different thread.

Any API calls should not done in the Main Thread, which is why you cannot return from an `enqueue`.

However, you can run the API call in-place, on the Main Thread. It is not recommonded, as it **will** make your Application UI freeze while the API call is being proccessed.

One way to do what you're trying to implement, is with a set of Callbacks.

You put 2 parameters in your method. `onSuccess`, and `onFailure`. Both are Lambdas, with `onSuccess` having a `bool` parameter, and `onFailure` having an `Exception` parameter.

This is how your code would look like

```
public static boolean testConnection(Function<Boolean, Void> onSuccess, Function<Exception, Void> onFailure) {
        
        apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(Api.class);
        
        Call<String> call = apiInterface.testConnection();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                
                if (response.body().equals("Connected")) {
                    onSuccess.invoke(true);
                } else {
                    onSuccess.invoke(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("infomessage", t.getMessage());
                onSuccess.invoke(false);
                onFailure.invoke(t);
            }
        });
        return isConnected;
    }
```

In your UI

```
testConnection((isConnected) -> {

}, (error) -> {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit's `enqueue` is a non-blocking call with an asynchronous callback. Instead use `execute()`